# Error TF2. Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator. Python interpreter state is not initialized It does not happen in TF1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This error is quite strange and gets me crazy because it does not prompt in Tensorflow 1.15. I create a data generator that works perfectly when using Tensorflow 1.15, but because I have some
Out of Memory problems that I could not manage in TF1, y upgrade to TF2 and I get this message at the beginning of the training.

I am using a HPC that has a Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB. It seems as if the GPU could not load the python interpreter, python 3.7.

Any thoughts? As I said, TF1 works perfectly.

```
2021-05-20 17:15:31.744926: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:107] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Failed precondition: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed precondition: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65302480/failed-precondition-python-interpreter-state-is-not-initialized-the-process-ma)

Comment: Add this code snippet `gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)
`. Thanks!